# Modify Filter of Fluent Bit doesn't add constant value

Tags: clickhouse, fluent-bit

Fluent bit v3.0.0 is configured on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS and on Windows server 2016 standart. The configs (fluent-bit.conf, parser.conf) on these linux and windows machines are absolutely the same. however I ran into a problem. The Modify [Filter] works correctly only on a Windows machine and does not work on Linux.

Fluent bit has been configured, which parses into two tables in clickhouse. The first table name is 'access', the second table name is 'flussonic'. The name of the column is 'server_ip' in the tables is the same.
Configured a Modify [Filter] that should add a constant value to the 'server_ip' columns in each of the two clickhouse tables.

fluent-bit.conf:

```
[FILTER]
name   modify
match  access
add    server_ip 192.168.1.2

[FILTER]
name   modify
match  flussonic
add    server_ip 192.168.1.2
```

In this case, the addition occurs only in 'flussonic', and a constant value is not written to 'access'.

I tried this setting:

```
[FILTER]
name  modify
match *
add   server_ip 192.168.1.2
```

In this case, the addition also occurs only in 'flussonic'.

I tried changing the name of the 'server_ip' column to 'ip_server'. No result.

There are no errors in the fluent bit logs that could help us understand the problem. I would be grateful if you tell me what to do  and where I am wrong. Because setting it up for the first time. Any ideas?